# Charles filter by domain name is not working with 4.0 version

Tags: charles-proxy

I need to see traffic from particular domain only. For that went to Proxy > Recording Settings? Include and added hostname `test.companyname.com`

Left all other fields blank (Protocol, Port, Part, Query fields)

But even after this I still see traffic from other sources like Slack and Google.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you check that include after, or is it not active? It works for me.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you please add your setup screen shot , I found documentation is not updated as per latest version

Comment: [this](https://monosnap.com/file/cnh1j6cOauB23r1cgxR9Bibp9UpRRi.png) and [this](https://monosnap.com/file/0CoLSHpVMHd1hUKZ3eTrOu5jrhngNn.png).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I do have same setting but ONLY "slack and google" are still getting through and showing me their traffic , other website traffic is not shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same bug. Restart Charles after change "Include" option solved the problem.